# Symbols and Numbers used on VSCode Extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, symbols

Can anyone please explain to me the meaning of the small blue triangle in the upper left corner of the python extension and the grey number on the lower left site of the python icon.

[image: screenshot of the python extension label]

Thank you!

P.S.: And please can anybody explain, why I cannot include an address like "Hi everybody"? It get's automatically removed.

Comment: I'm surprised there's no mention in the [VSCode User Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace). I spent over an hour trying to get rid of the grey number. I thought it asked me to update the package

Answer (score 5):

The *blue triangle* with star inside is a tag for **recommended extension**.

The *number in the lower left* is attached to packages of extensions, and indicates the **number of extensions** in this package.